# How can I speed up my computer, now that I've installed Linux?

Tags: system-installation

Can I delete my Windows 7 software, as well as any old files that Linux doesn't require to run? I'm new to Linux.

If I can, where/how do I delete it?

Comment: Did you install ubuntu via wubi? If not, how did you install it? Did you delete your windows partition?

Comment: @MiJyn Actually, I downloaded the .iso from the official website. I then transferred onto a virtual .iso drive, and installed it that way. I don't know what you mean by wubi. But, how do I do that?

Comment: OK first maybe you sould check this http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest before doing anything to your windows... after that get to know linux distro then every thing else will happen. :)

Comment: If you are a slave to an iPhone, be aware that no Apple software runs smoothly on any Linux platform, so you may need to keep Windows installed for iTunes alone.

Answer (score 0):

Linux is significantly more efficient than Windows. If you are really concerned about speed, try messing with your startup applications.

Linux primarily uses the ext3 or ext4 file system, which unlike NTFS, does not need defragmentation. So your computer won't slow down over time because of file fragmentation on the HDD. The Linux filesystem is more intelligent than that. :)

If you are new to Linux, I would recommend Linux Mint over Ubuntu.

Comment: I disagree with your suggestion, I tried Linux Mint alongside Ubuntu and found it less easy to master and after a few weeks, deleted it. It is up to the user to decide which OS is best.

Comment: Linux actually is less efficient and slower on startup I had windows installed with my Lenovo laptop and exchanged it for Ubuntu, so I do have the comparison. It's also less ressource friendly: http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2014/02/linux-on-the-nuc-using-ubuntu-mint-fedora-and-the-steamos-beta/

I also prefer unity over Mint Cinnamon. It's a more modern interface.